# Bulk insert in MySQL with stored procedure

Tags: mysql, xml

From my C#, I am creating datatable at run time. I want to pass this datatable into stored procedure so that data will insert together into the table.
I am using MySQL as database. What is the MySQL equivalent of passing xml for multiple insert in SQL-Server?

I generate XML from dataset and passed it to stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `RouteLocationVehicleTimeInsert`(

    IN xml VARCHAR(1000000)
    )
BEGIN
  SET @x=1;
  SET @val=xml;
    WHILE @x<=4 DO
        SET @vehicleId=EXTRACTVALUE(@val, 'NewDataSet/Table1/vehicle_id[$@x]');
        SET @routeId = EXTRACTVALUE(@val, 'NewDataSet/Table1/route_id[$@x]');
        SET @locationId = EXTRACTVALUE(@val, 'NewDataSet/Table1/location_id[$@x]');
        SET @arrivalTime = EXTRACTVALUE(@val, 'NewDataSet/Table1/arrival_time[$@x]');   
    INSERT INTO `rm.routelocation_fm.vehicle_time`(`vehicle_id`,`route_id`,`location_id`,`arrival_time`)
    VALUES(@vehicleId,@routeId,@locationId,@arrivalTime);
    SET @x=@x+1;
   END WHILE;
END@@
```

But it doesn't help. When i test the sql statement written in SP i gives multipl values in same column, like as below

```
SET @val='<NewDataSet>
<Table1>
<vehicle_id>1</vehicle_id>
<route_id>5</route_id>
<location_id>1</location_id>
<arrival_time>00:00</arrival_time>
</Table1>
<Table1>
    <vehicle_id>2</vehicle_id>
    <route_id>5</route_id>
    <location_id>2</location_id>
    <arrival_time>00:00</arrival_time>
  </Table1></NewDataSet>';
SET @x=1;

        SET @vehicle_id= EXTRACTVALUE(@val, 'NewDataSet/Table1/vehicle_id[1]');
        SELECT @vehicle_id;
```

it gives result as 1  1 in same column. where they are two records.

Comment: Yes I managed to pass data in xml format as below,SET @val='<NewDataSet><Table1><vehicle_id>1</vehicle_id><route_id>5</route_id><location_id>1</location_id><arrival_time>00:00</arrival_time></Table1>
<Table1>
    <vehicle_id>1</vehicle_id>
    <route_id>5</route_id>
    <location_id>2</location_id>
    <arrival_time>00:00</arrival_time>
  </Table1></NewDataSet>';
SET @x=1;
  

        
        SET @locationId = EXTRACTVALUE(@val, 'NewDataSet/Table1/location_id[$@x]');
        SELECT @locationId;

Comment: But when i test this using select statement result is getting as " 1 2" instaer 1

Comment: can you add that to your original post...

Comment: Updated original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your bottom example you have `<Table1></Table1>` block twice. And as per definition in [XML Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue) documentation:

> If multiple matches are found, the content of the first child text
>   node of each matching element is returned (in the order matched) as a
>   single, space-delimited string.

It returns the contents of first `vehicle_id` in both `<Table1>` blocks. If you want the id from just first `<Table1>`, change your XPath to `'NewDataSet/Table1[1]/vehicle_id[1]'`.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial xpath: `NewDataSet/Table1/vehicle_id[1]` doesn't really help because it return first `vehicle_id` from each `Table1` parent. Since there is only one `vehicle_id` in each `Table1` already, the xpath doesn't produce any effect.

Usually, to get only first match from an xpath we wrap the entire xpath within `()[1]`, something like this :

```
(NewDataSet/Table1/vehicle_id)[1]
```

Unfortunately, above xpath syntax doesn't seems to be supported by MySQL's `EXTRACTVALUE()`. You need to resort to something more complex to get *similar* result :

```
NewDataSet/Table1[vehicle_id][1]/vehicle_id[1]
```

Above xpath get the *first* `vehicle_id` from the *first* `Table1` having child `vehicle_id`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/8464)